Flashing Yocto Image on Jetson TX2 Module Results in U-Boot Partition Errors
I'm working with a custom board that uses an Nvidia Jetson TX2 module, and I'm encountering issues when flashing a Yocto-built image. The process works intermittently, but most of the time, the device fails to boot and halts at U-Boot with partition errors on the eMMC.
Here are the details:

Hardware: Custom board with Nvidia Jetson TX2 module.
OS: Yocto image built using the kirkstone branch of meta-tegra
(GitHub https://github.com/OE4T/meta-tegra/tree/kirkstone-l4t-r32.7.x). Host Environment: Ubuntu 20.04.
Connection: The board is in recovery mode and connected to the host
machine via a USB-A to USB-B 3.2 cable.
Flashing Process: The flash script was generated by Yocto.

Issue:
The flashing process completes successfully according to the script.
However, the device does not boot up correctly afterward. It stops at U-Boot with some partition issues on the eMMC.
What I've Tried:

Verified that the board is in recovery mode.
Checked the USB connection and cable quality.
Rebuilt the Yocto image and flash script multiple times.

I also looked through NVIDIA's posts on their forum, but most refer to Yocto image errors, and the image is 95% ok, because it works at our partner and I also tried to upload images tested by other developers.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with flashing Yocto images on Jetson TX2, or does anyone have suggestions on what might be going wrong? Any pointers to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated!
